# How to insert data in database in multiple tables in SQL Server using ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am creating Bill invoice. Database table are `tblCustomer`, `tblBill`, `tblBillDetail`.

The data entry is on single page. On button click `Create_bill`, I need to insert data into the respective tables.

How to create such a query?

Please tell me. If my query is incomplete, please comment .

Comment: Not much details here. I assume you want to insert into tblBill and tblBillDetail? You will just to create 2 insert statements. Off topic, but prefixing your table with tbl is not a great practice.

Comment: You need to show some code, effort and the table structure.

Comment: So far, your query isn't *incomplete* - it's **inexistent** .... show us something you've tried!

Comment: I'd hardly recommend to use a SP for this kind of querys. Edit question with more details on your progress so far.